# Is it possible to use the uber api to identify a driver?

Tags: uber-api

working in a vehicle protection association and I need to identify which of our associates are uber drivers, is this possible to be done using the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation, there are only these endpoints https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api#endpoints.

And I think none of them solves the problem.